# JavaScript/JQuery rotate an image on click using speed and degrees

Tags: javascript

How could I make an image rotate when I click on it and every time that I click on it the speed of it's rotation should increase.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$("body").on("click", "#buttonId", function () {
    $(".north, canvas").rotate(90);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css transform property to transform html element.to rotate with jquery you can write a method which add the transofrm property to the element with respective angle.

`$.fn.rotate = function(deg){
     deg = deg+"deg";
     $(this).css("transform","rotate(deg)");
}`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var theImage = document.getElementById("TheImage");
var degree = 0;
var increment = 0;
var firstClick = true;

function rotateTheImage() {
 degree += increment;
 theImage.style.transform = "rotate(" + degree + "deg)";
}


theImage.addEventListener("click", function() {

 if(firstClick) {
  setInterval(rotateTheImage, 100);
  firstClick = false;
 }
 
 increment++;
 
}, false);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Rotate by Click</title>
</head>
<body>

<svg id="TheImage" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="124" height="124">
<path fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="5" d="m61,7a55,55
0 1,0 2,0zm1,0v110m39-16-78-78m78,0-78,78m-16-39h110"/>
</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

ADDED: JQUERY version of JAVASCRIPT Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Rotate by Click</title>
</head>

<body>

<svg id="TheImage" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="124" height="124">
<path fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="5" d="m61,7a55,55
0 1,0 2,0zm1,0v110m39-16-78-78m78,0-78,78m-16-39h110"/>
</svg>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
<script>
var degree = 0;
var increment = 0;
var firstClick = true;

function rotateTheImage() {
 degree += increment;
 $("#TheImage").css("transform", "rotate(" + degree + "deg)");
}

$("#TheImage").click(function() {

 if(firstClick) {
  setInterval(rotateTheImage, 100);
  firstClick = false;
 }
 
 increment++;
 
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Just a quick implementation. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <style>
    #image{
       -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
        -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
        -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
        transition-duration: 0.8s;

        -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
        -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
        -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
         transition-property: transform;
    }

  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <img id="image" width="50" height="50" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/82/Facebook_icon.jpg">
    <script>
        $(function(){
            var rotateByAngle = 90;
            $("#image").click(function(){
                rotateByAngle+= 90;
                $(this).css({
                    "transform": "rotate(" + rotateByAngle + "deg)",
                    "-webkit-transform" : "rotate(" + rotateByAngle + "deg)"
                })
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```